# How to start with particular Image using the iPhone WWDC 2010 - 104 PhotoScroller

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, wwdc

I am going through the Sample code of iPhone WWDC 2010 - 104 PhotoScroller App.

It's working great with my project related images (PDF Page Images)

Now I want to start the app from a custom image no  - Say 5.
And it should show 6th image on next swipe and 4th on previous swipe.

Can anyone help in this Regard ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try modifying the contentOffset of the UIScrollView.

Depending on the width frame you should set it to something like :

```
imagePos * scrollView.frame.width
```

where imagePos begin to 0 and end to (nbrImage - 1)

Good Luck ;-)

Comment: Hi Vinzius, How to detect touches in the PhotoSCroller App. I want to Zoom the photo on double Tap. The Touchesbegan method is being called in TilingView Class. Then I used [super touchesbegan: withevent:] and now the touches are in the ImageScrollView Class. How to get these touch events in PhotoViewController.  How to achieve the zoom in and zoom out on touch ?

Answer (score 0):

I made it this way. 
I have UIScrollView *contentView and in init I calculate frame for photo I want to display and just scroll contentView to that rect. tilePages will do everything else for you

[contentView scrollRectToVisible:[self frameForPageAtIndex:_index] animated:NO];